# Check if a command exists using qmake

Tags: command, qmake, exists

I am working on a project which incorporates C code, as well as (MASM-like) assembly. I want to be able to compile it on Linux, as well as Windows, thus I am using a third-party assembler (jwasm) as follows:

```
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += jwasm -coff -Fo$$assembly_obj $$PWD/assembly.asm
```

(here, assembly_obj holds the directory I want jwasm to save the output. Oh, by the way: when using jwasm it is critical to *first* specify all the parameters, and only at the end the input files, otherwise it will ignore the parameters)

To make it easier for other people to compile the project, I would like to be able to check if jwasm is in their path, and if not, emit an `error()` telling them how to fix this. However, I am not sure if this is even possible using qmake. I have tried:

```
exists("jwasm") {  # Always false
    message("jwasm found!")
}
```

as well as:

```
packagesExist(jwasm) { # Always true
    message("jwasm found!")
}
```

I have looked around in the qmake docs, but couldn't find any other alternatives...

Comment: Have you thought about using `system()`. It returns the output of command if it exists, and fails otherwise. You can try ex. `system(where jwasm)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in function in original Qt's qmake (maybe will add such function to my [XD](http://github.com/top-master/qtbase)).

But you could instead check the "binary search-paths" manually, maybe by iterating `$$(PATH)` (after splitting) and then checking with `exists(...)`.

However, there are two `system(...)` functions, where one is a test-function and the other a replace-function (`system(...)` vs `$$system(...)`).

Meaning if all you nead is better user experience, you could check if the test-function runs fine, something like:

```
 ! system(my-command --my-option) {
    error(Requires my-command to be installed.)
}
```

Or even in one line:

```
system(my-command --my-option) | error(Some error message.)
```

**Note** that older QMake versions need you to remove spaces from " | " and " ! " part.